# How do I create a function that pulls two values from my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I want to create a function that basically pulls two specific values or "cells" from my data frame. The data frame is a little large so I attached a picture of it. My current code for the function

```
def return_riskscore(CountryA, CountryB):
    i = CountryA
    j = CountryB
    senti_value = main7.at[i,j]
    return senti_value
```

Then I used the following to apply the function to the dataframe.

```
main7["Value"] = main7.apply(return_riskscore(CountryA = 'Ukraine ', CountryB = 'Russia'))
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/bl/qq18pm0d3kv24sfpjxbb_d2w0000gn/T/ipykernel_29770/4285294519.py in <module>
----> 1 main7["Value"] = main7.apply(return_riskscore(CountryA = 'Ukraine', CountryB = 'Russia'))

/var/folders/bl/qq18pm0d3kv24sfpjxbb_d2w0000gn/T/ipykernel_29770/1369879570.py in return_riskscore(CountryA, CountryB)
      2     i = CountryA
      3     j = CountryB
----> 4     senti_value = main7.at[i,j]
      5     return senti_value
      6     #for i in range(len(main7)):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2273             return self.obj.loc[key]
   2274 
-> 2275         return super().__getitem__(key)
   2276 
   2277     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2220 
   2221         key = self._convert_key(key)
-> 2222         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   2223 
   2224     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   3577 
   3578         try:
-> 3579             loc = engine.get_loc(index)
   3580             return series._values[loc]
   3581         except AttributeError:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'Ukraine'
```

More specifically, I want to be able to pull country A's and country B's value.
Is there another way to achieve this? an example output is the value (number) at the specified Row , Country title. For example if Country A = Ukraine and Country B = Russia, then the output I expect is 1.0 [Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR3sO.png)

Comment: apply need function's name without `()` and arguments - and it runs it many times and it sends single row/column to this function - so you may have to create lambda or new function which get only row/column.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: is `Ukraine` and `Russia` as column's name?

Comment: I don't know what you try to get in finall column but `apply` doesn't work as you use it.

Comment: I'm not sure but `at` may expect row number as first argument. Doc: [pandas.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

Comment: Ukraine and Russia are a col title and a row title, I want to access that specific cell

Comment: Use `return_riskscore` without any parameters in apply and set `CountryA` and `CountryB` manually in the function.

Comment: I checked `at[]` on some example at it should work - but maybe first check what you really have in `main7`, maybe it doesn't use `Ukraine` as index

Comment: I think I found problem - you have `space` at the end `'Ukraine '` in `CountryA = 'Ukraine '` and this can make problem. But error message shows that you use `'Ukraine` without space. So you show different code, and error shows different code.

Comment: Let me check the spacing.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the output you needed as well. Because to get the risk score between any two countries in the dataframe, just try:

`CountryA, CountryB = 'Ukraine', 'Russia'
risk_score = main7.at[CountryA, CountryB]`

Comment: Sure, an example output is the value (number) at the specified Row , Country title. For example if Country A = Ukraine and Country B = Russia, then the output I expect is 1.0.